# How to install security patches on CentOS 7.x

Tags: security, centos7, patch-management

I need to install several security and apllication patches.  An example of a patch considered critical is below:

Vulnerabilities
134087 - CentOS 7 : kernel (CESA-2020:0374)-

**Synopsis**
The remote CentOS host is missing one or more security updates.

**Description**
An update for kernel is now available for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.

Red Hat Product Security has rated this update as having a security impact of Important. A Common Vulnerability Scoring System (CVSS) base score, which gives a detailed severity rating, is available for each vulnerability from the CVE link(s) in the References section.

The kernel packages contain the Linux kernel, the core of any Linux operating system.

I did yum update --security command but the problem is still there after another scan from security team.   Not sure if this should use different procedure and requires server restart.

Could someone enlighten me please?

Answer (score 1):

`yum update --security` does not work with CentOS, due to the repos missing security tag information.

You need to issue a more invasive, system wide update with `yum update` or, alternatively, to only update the affected packages.